# MySQL - Somar valores de uma coluna e também trazer valor de cada linha

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, union

Eu tenho uma determinada coluna e preciso retornar tanto a soma dos valores da mesma, como também os valores individuais de cada linha.

Eu fiz um teste com **UNION** e até deu certo, a primeira linha retornou a SOMA e as demais os valores individuais de cada linha. Porém eu não sei se isso está certo e se tem uma outra maneira de fazer isso.
Eu fiz assim, está certo?

```
SELECT SUM(val_resgate) AS resgate FROM ETAPA WHERE fk_servico=39 
UNION
SELECT val_resgate FROM ETAPA WHERE fk_servico=39
```

Answer (score 2):

Sim é uma forma aceitável de fazer mas no caso do MySQL recomendo usar o **UNION ALL** e não **UNION** pois o default dele é usar o **UNION DISTINCT**.
Também vale lembrar que o comportamento com o ORDER BY do UNION difere se ele esta agrupado com o SELECT ou no final do UNION onde ele ordena o resultado todo.

Usando seu exemplo:

Isso faz ele colocar o total no topo e ordenar os outros valores crescente

```
(SELECT SUM(val_resgate) AS resgate FROM ETAPA WHERE fk_servico=39)
UNION ALL
(SELECT val_resgate FROM ETAPA WHERE fk_servico=39 ORDER BY val_resgate)
```

Já desta forma o toral irá ser a última linha do resultado

```
(SELECT SUM(val_resgate) AS resgate FROM ETAPA WHERE fk_servico=39)
UNION ALL
(SELECT val_resgate FROM ETAPA WHERE fk_servico=39)
ORDER BY val_resgate
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você pode utilizar o "group by" com "with rollup" para obter essa soma no final. Ex:

```
SELECT SUM(val_resgate) AS resgate 
FROM ETAPA 
WHERE fk_servico=39
GROUP BY id_etapa WITH ROLLUP
```

Espero que ajude